# Mongoose Static Not Returning Object After Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to make a method in my model to return the mongodb id of a user given his twitterid. It looks something like this:

```
userSchema.statics = {

    getMongoIdByTwitterName : function (twittername){
        this.findOne(({twitterID : req.user.id},
            function(err, user){

            };
        )
    }
}
```

But this obviously doesnt return anything, how do I make this function return the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a callback function?

```
userSchema.statics = {
    getMongoIdByTwitterName : function (twittername, callback){
        this.findOne(findOne({twitterID : req.user.id},
            callback(err, user);
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: how is a cb function is going to help ? somewhere else in my application I want to be able to do var mongoid = User.getMongoIdByTwitterName(twittername)

Comment: The only way to 'return' a value inside a closure is to use callback function in javascript. This is the nature of JS.